# How to get a unique value from the html form in a auto generating for loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a Html form in a loop. So when my PHP script fetch a row from my DB each row has a same html form form attached to it. Then I take those form values and pass it to a ajax script which then call a php file which then update those values into DB . The problem is when I Update those value the form the updates every column in all the rows.(The sample image attached below. My Criticality and Priority column has the same values after storing the update values in the Db)[image]

**And yes I have a Auto-generated primary key in both the tables **

Thats my loop

```
          <?php
      foreach($results as $data){

          echo '<tbody>
              <tr class="dropDown">
              <td>1</td>
              <td>'.$data['Title'].'</td>
              <td>'.$data['criticality'].'</td>
              <td>'.$data['Priority'].'</td>
              <td>'.$data['Description'].'</td>
              <td>'.$data['Date_Submitted'].'</td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>';

      }

    ?>
```

That's my web form:

```
        <form action="/action_page.php">
      <fieldset>
        <label>XYZ Questions </label><br>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">
            <label>YES</label>
        </label>
          <label class="radio-inline left">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">
            <label>NO</label>
        </label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <label>XYZ Questions </label><br>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio1">
            <label>YES</label>
        </label>
          <label class="radio-inline left">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio1">
            <label>NO</label>
        </label>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

That's my ajax script to get the values

```
      var launchAjax = function () { // event handler for button click
      $.get(
     "php/inbetween.php/",
     {
         question: $("[name=optradio]:checked").val(),
         question1: $("[name=optradio1]:checked").val(),

     }
   );
  }

  $("#no").click(launchAjax);
```

and that's how convert those values and save a number in to a bd

```
    function getMark($answer, $mark = 1){ 
    $result = 0;
    if($answer == 'YES'){
        $result = $mark;
    }
    return $result;
}
    $p = 0;
    $p += getMark($question, 1); // provide the answer and the mark
    $p += getMark($question1, .5);

    $c = 0;
    $c += getMark($question, 0.5); // provide the answer and the mark
    $c += getMark($question1, 1);
```

That's my Php script to update the form values in a table

```
 $command1 = "UPDATE rating SET criticality = '$c' , Priority = '$p'";

   // prepare and executing
$stmt1 = $dbh->prepare($command1);
$result1 = $stmt1->execute();
```

Comment: Where is your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I don't know which parameters to put in where clause in my sql query. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Your HTML/AJAX needs to pass the primary key (or a something to uniquely identify a row) to PHP. You would use this to update a specific row(s). Ex. `<td>'.$data['Id'].'</td>`. Then pass that to your `WHERE` clause. Also, you need to read about prepared statements. https://phpdelusions.net/pdo. Read a decent AJAX/PHP/MYSQL tutorial - https://programmerblog.net/php-pdo-ajax-tutorial-example/. Notice that they include the primary key in the HTML form.

Comment: Oh great, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your SQL code:

```
UPDATE rating SET criticality = '$c' , Priority = '$p';
```

This is asking your database to update the table 'rating', and set 'criticality' and 'priority' to the values stored in `$c` and `$p`. Notice how it's not telling the database *which* row to update, so it's running the update on ALL rows.

Each of your database rows should have a primary key, which is usually an incrementing integer. This is usually the way you'd carry out this kind of update:

```
UPDATE rating SET criticality = '$c' , Priority = '$p' WHERE id = '$id';
```

You'll need to find a way to include the ID of the row in your Ajax call, which your PHP script can then pass to MySQL to update the correct row.

Comment: That a problem I am having a hard time to find a way to include an ID of row in my ajax call which my php script can then pass to my sql to update the correct row.Thank you for replying.

Comment: It's difficult to work out from your examples how each table row is associated to it's corresponding form. You could include a link in each table row to open the form, and pass through the ID that way.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking that as my last option to make it work. Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a WHERE clause un your UPDATE statement.

```
$command1 = "UPDATE rating SET criticality = '$c' , Priority = '$p' WHERE id = $id ";
```

That will only update the row that matches the id you pass.

@tombeynon got there first haha

Comment: That a problem I am having a hard time to find a way to include an ID of row in my ajax call which my php script can then pass to my sql to update the correct row.Thank you for replying.

Comment: In your foreach loop set the tr elements id attribute to $data['id"]. that should set the id to your row's primary key ( remember to to select it in your query )

Comment: I tried to did that i.e.    <td>'.$data['NO'].'</td> . In which NO is my ID column for each row. But the problem is to pass this in the ajax call and then using php to update the sql with where clause.

Comment: I have to say it is quite difficult to find a way to do this based on your examples. As @tombeynon suggested you may have to pass the id as a parameter in a link